# What are the best practices for adding icons to Zend Framework applications?

Tags: zend-framework, view

I want to add icons to my application. I've put the icons in public_html/images/icons/ and I want a DRY way to put them in my view-scripts. So I'd preferably not repeat..

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl();?>/images/icons/plus-circle.png"</a>
```

..for every icon.
I'd prefer a simple object+function call.
What is a best practice for this?

I *suspect* I should use a view helper, but I don't understand those fully yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an View Helper for this.

```
class My_View_Helper_Icon extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{

    public function icon($icon)
    {
        // not sure if you can use $this->baseUrl(); inside view helper
        $baseUrl = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getBaseUrl();
        $xhtml = sprintf('<img src="%s/images/icons/%s"', $baseUrl, $icon);

        return $xhtml;
    }

}
```

Inside your view

```
echo $this->icon('plus-circle.png');
```

Comment: return '<img src="' . $this->view->baseUrl() . '"/images/icons/' . $icon . '" />';

Comment: I've adapted your answer in a new answer to make it work in my application. But your answer is basically good, as far as I can tell.

Comment: This is nice, but you can't add parameters to the `img` tag this way. You should subclass `Zend_View_Helper_HtmlTag` instead.

Comment: @takeshin I've implemented it this way so I'm sure it does work :) But why would using Zend_View_Helper_HtmlTag be a better idea?

Comment: @Niels Sure it works. But look at the methods `Zend_View_Helper_HtmlTag` provides. There are methods for getting proper closing tags and HTML attributes, so your code could be doctype independent and you can pass any HTML attributes to your tag.

Answer (score 0):

I have a view helper which has the method `$this->app()->getFileUrl('favicon.ico')`. Which will search the theme's location first then the public location. I assign this to a variable at the top of my view script and all done.

The source for the view helper and front controller plugin can be found here:
http://github.com/balupton/balphp/tree/master/trunk/lib/Bal/

Or rather the code directly:
http://github.com/balupton/balphp/blob/master/trunk/lib/Bal/Controller/Plugin/App/Abstract.php#L721

Comment: "Which will search the theme's location first then the public location." That sounds quite resource intensive, have you tested this for speed?

Comment: Performance of this is trivial; It's barely used (and where it is, result is cached), performance issues would just be with two `file_exists` checks (one for themes, one for public).

Answer (score 0):

Using @ArneRie's answer:

In views/helpers/Icon.php I've written the following class:

```
class Zend_View_Helper_Icon extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    //$icon is the name of an icon without the ".png" at the end because all icons
    //are .png
    public function icon($icon)
    {
        $baseUrl = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getBaseUrl();
        return sprintf('<img src="%s/images/icons/%s.png">', $baseUrl, $icon);
    }
}
```

In my view file in views/scripts/index/index.phtml I then call the method of the Icon object like so:

```
<?php echo $this->icon('plus-circle');?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version:

```
class My_View_Helper_Icon extends Zend_View_Helper_HtmlElement
{
    /**
     *
     * @param string $src Icon source
     * @param array $attribs HTML Atrtibutes and values
     * @param string $tag HTML tag name
     * @return string HTML
     */
    public function icon($src, $attribs = array(), $tag = 'img')
    {
        $attribs['src'] = $this->view->baseUrl($src);    
        $html = '<' . $tag . $this->_htmlAttribs($attribs) . $this->getClosingBracket();

        return $html;
    }
}
```